# What happened to the new room mate?

Tags: plot-explanation, new-girl

In the television series, New Girl, S01E24, it is shown that Smith and Jess conduct interview for new room mate to replace Nick. They select one of them and he also moves in with his luggage but at the end of the Episode Nick just walks in back to the Apartment and there is no mention of the new room mate at all.

Comment: Schmidt, not Smith.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a "mention" of sorts of the new roommate, Neil, by the images in the final scene ... Nick just takes back into his room without saying anything, everyone dances to AC/DC, and Neil is meekly sitting on the couch. Such an image quite clearly represents that there is no room for Neil because Nick is back in.